# Хочу получить ключи из словаря Python

Tags: python, vkontakte-api, словари

Разбираюсь в модуле vk_api!!!
`vk_audio.get`- Получить список аудиозаписей пользователя.
При выводе мы получаем много значений (ключей).
Так вот, мне нужны все названия песен.
К сожалению, я могу вывести только одно название песни.

```
i = vk_audio.get(owner_id=my_id)[63] 63 - номер трека.
t = i["title"]
print(t)
```

Из-за того, что я получаю информацию об одном треке, python даёт мне его название.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если убрать цифру 63, то есть получить список всех аудиозаписей, python выдаёт ошибку.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подумав, я решил написать код, который постоянно будет мне давать по одной аудиозаписи

```
  k = 0
  while k < 5: #здесь будет макс. кол-во песен.
      i = vk_audio.get(owner_id=my_id)[k]
      k += 1
      print(i["title"])
  else:
      print("stop")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Да, я получаю что хочу, но процесс очень долгий.

Подскажите, как исправить ошибку. Чтобы получить сразу все "title"

Comment: Никак. Без цикла тут не обойтись. Могу лишь сказать, что цикл `for` сделает это немного быстрее и очевиднее.

Comment: Хотя знаете, попробуйте убрать `[63]`, а следующую строку просто закомментировать. Возможно, это то, что Вы хотите.

Comment: @nomnoms12 
Если убрать 63, я получу очень много информации, включая длительность, ссылку на скачивание, также название. Мне нужно только название.

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понимаю, то в вашем коде с циклом вы на каждой итерации делаете новый запрос, получаете информацию по ВСЕМ песням, но при этом реально используете только информацию об одной песне за раз.

Кажется, это можно значительно ускорить, если сначала один раз сделать запрос к вконтакту, а уже потом в цикле разобрать поэлементно:

```
all_audio = vk_audio.get(owner_id=my_id)
for item in all_audio:
    print(item["title"])
```

Answer (score 0):

***Пример:***

```py
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.audio import VkAudio


vk = VkApi(login=[Логин], password=[Пароль])
vk.auth()

audio = VkAudio(vk)

for music in audio.get(owner_id=[Ваш owner_id]):
    artist = music['artist']
    title = music['title']
    print(f'{artist}: {title}')
```

***stdout:***

```html
Belleruche: Wasted Time
Young Galaxy: Phantoms
JIM: I'm not who you think
Siriusmo, Mr. Oizo: Doppelklick
Esbe: Addicted
Mabuta: Log Out Shut Down (Gourmet Remix)
...
```